# Setting up write permission in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I recently deployed a laravel project on DigitalOcean ubuntu server as a non root user by pulling the project from github. Then I ran the following commands to grant permission to storage logs from the project root path

`sudo chown -R $USER:www-data .`

`sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`

`sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`

`sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache`

`sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Then the application started working fine, logs were written as intended and the logs looked like this

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 elo www-data   79352 Feb 27 22:00 laravel-2021-02-27.log

But when a new log file was generated, the logs group changed again causing certain log information not to be written to log

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 elo elo          901 Feb 28 08:00 laravel-2021-02-28.log

What could be the reason for this? It looks like the permissions I have set is not correct. How should the permissions be set?

Comment: You must change the nginx  php-fpm group  or the user group that running the command

Comment: you mean by running `sudo usermod -a -G www-data elo` ?  i did this but result is the same

Comment: What makes the logs  web service or command?

Comment: if command use this -> sudo usermod -g primarygroupname username

Comment: web service. when a post is made to an endpoint, i want a log written to file

Comment: so you must change nginx and php-fpm user 
in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -> user user group;

and php-fpm -> edit /etc/php.fpm.d/www.conf


user = user
group = group
listen.owner = user
listen.group = group

Comment: Maybe $USER has no complete access to give 'ug+rwx' to the 'storage bootstrap/cache'. Did you check this at first command: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .`? btw, I use www-data:www-data.

Comment: @iazaran I am considering actually using the same. I will try this and see if it changes tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I also have related problem, but my problem is the log file is not writable(-r----x--t).  I am still dont know the real reason, but to fix that in my case I know 2 solutions:

1. change `LOG_CHANNEL` in .env to single instead of stack/daily.
2. remove `permission` config in `config/logging.php`

   ```
    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
   //   'permission' => 777, //remove or comment this
        'days' => 14,
    ],
   ```